# How to make VS Code debug Electron App reproducibly?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-debugger

I used [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) to create an app which has *Hot reload, Typescript, Crossenv, Webpack, Babel, React devTools, and vscode debug configs* built in.

Question: How do I get VSCode to reproducibly attach/debug this app? I've posted a github issue [here](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/2591) with examples of the inconsistent debugging and configurations.

For completeness, here is the current relevant settings in my project:

***package.json***

```
...

  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./app/main.prod.js",
    "start-main-debug": "yarn start-main-dev --inspect=5858 --remote-debugging-port=9223",
    "start-main-dev": "cross-env START_HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r ./internals/scripts/BabelRegister ./app/main.dev.ts",
    "start-renderer-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.babel.js",
  },
...
```

***launch.json***

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Electron: Main",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": ["start-main-debug"],
      "preLaunchTask": "Start Webpack Dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "Electron: Renderer",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9223,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "timeout": 15000
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Electron: All",
      "configurations": ["Electron: Main", "Electron: Renderer"]
    }
  ]
}
```

***Environment***

```
Node version : 14.11.0
VSCode version: 1.49.1
electron-react-boilerplate version or branch : 1.3.0
Operating System and version : Darwin 10.15.5
```

Other files same as in boilerplate, e.g.
[main.dev.ts](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.dev.ts)

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I'm simply killing the process and clearing the breakpoints, then restarting/resetting. This hits all breakpoints, but does so in a somewhat non-deterministic way...

Definitely open to better solutions if others have them!

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Comment: @BarisLaPaz nope, still killing and clearing breakpoints... I've actually switched to in browser debugger with source mapping because of all the setup pain and inconsistency